# Organizing floats in a multi-file project

Tags: sectioning, floats, organisation

I find it convenient to manage my papers on a one-section-one-file basis. However, I also find it convenient to have my figures defined in the corresponding section.

Unfortunately, these two requirements conflict with the placement of floating environments. Say I have to sections A and B and two large images B1 and B2. Now when I am using a two-column layout and A covers one page and half of a column, I need to put B1 into section A to make it appear on top of the page which contains the beginning of B.

Here's my general layout:

```
p1:
TI TLE
AA  AA
AA  AA
AA  AA

p2:
B1  B1
AA  BB  
AA  BB
BB  BB

p3:
B2  B2
BB  BB
BB
BB
```

I can make this work using the following:

```
\section{A}
A content ...
\begin{figure*}[t]
B1
\end{figure*}
further A content

\section{B}
\begin{figure*}[t]
B2
\end{figure*}
B content
```

Apparently, the floating algorithm of tex can only move floats "downwards", which is kind of logical, since the "upwards" portions are already set. However, as I said, this is kind of ugly in project management terms: When I want to reuse a section for a different paper, I can never be sure to get all the contents by just moving a file.

Is there a better way than to declare my floats in a previous section?

(If you want a working example, I'd need to know how to generate an arbitrary length blind text and some arbitrary content floats)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `input` (rather than `\include`) the file structure has essentially no effect on the typesetting.

So you can put you page wide figures for section B in section B's file, just place it before the `\section` there is no need to put it in section A's file.

So if this works in a single file

```
\section{A}
A content ...
\begin{figure*}[t]
B1
\end{figure*}

\section{B}
\begin{figure*}[t]
B2
\end{figure*}
B content
```

you can have three files

**main.tex**

```
\input{a}
\input{b}
```

**a.tex**

```
\section{A}
A content ...
```

**b.tex**

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
B1
\end{figure*}

\section{B}
\begin{figure*}[t]
B2
\end{figure*}
B content
```

Comment: This will typeset B1 after the contents of A, hence the floating will start on page 2, and I cannot make it move "updwards".

Comment: Yes I saw later (questions are always clearer if they have working document that demonstrates the problem) I was going by your "I can make this work"  in one col mode floats will move up the current page but not in 2 col. probably your best bet is to put the wide figure in its own file so you have b.tex and b-fig.tex and just \input{b-fig} at whateverf point inside a that you need, that at least makes it easy to collect all of section b to another document